# Calculating Library Fine

Tags: java

I was trying to calculate the library fine between my `issued date` and `due date`, what should I input instead of
`LocalDate today=LocalDate.now();` if I already have an `issued date` in my jtable, not the current date today, to calculate and compute with my `due_date`.

```
String duedate=rs.getString("due_date");
LocalDate today=LocalDate.now();
LocalDate dueday=LocalDate.parse(duedate);


Long day_gap=ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(dueday, today);

if(day_gap>0)
{
    t3.setText(day_gap.toString());
    long fine=5*day_gap;
    t4.setText(String.valueOf(fine));
}   
else
{
```

Comment: nevermind already solved it.

Comment: Please provide your own answer.  It may be helpful to others that find your question later.